# How to properly extend JHipster User Entity

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, jhipster

I started a new JHipster project recently and I have a requirement in the project for extending a built-in User entity.

For example to add some new attributes (and columns in the database to persist those). But, since this is built-in functionality and the User entity is not listed in .jhipster folder I'm wandering of a proper way to do it.

The simplest option would be to change User.java and liquibase migration xmls and all associated files but that would probably be an obstacle for future jhipster upgrades (running `yo jhipster` inside project folder like it is explained here [jhipster docs](https://jhipster.github.io/2016/03/23/jhipster-release-3.0.0.html) ).
Another possible route could probably be to create a new entity which would be in a one-to-one relation to the User entity, but I'm not sure how to exactly do this: Using `yo jhipster:entity` or ?

Has anyone successfully done this previously? What are the best practices I should follow in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest solution to be able to easily follow JHipster upgrades is to create a new entity (e.g. UserExtraInfo) with a one-to-one relationship with User and the owner of the relationship should be the new entity as we don't want to modify User. You'd generate the new entity using `yo jhipster:entity`.

Due to a [related issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3773) you must use release JHipster 3.5.0 at least to get this working.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I tried forking jhipster generator and running entity sub generator after doing `npm link` but generator is still behaving the same as the one installed using `npm install -g generator-jhipster` and it's showing that it is v3.4.2.

What am  I doing wrong?

Comment: did you run npm install before npm link in clone directory? version means nothing as it is still 3.4.2 on master

Comment: Yes, I first run `npm install` in jhipster project folder then switch to cloned generator repo and do `npm link` and then tried running `yo jhipster:entity UserInfo` in the jhipster project root.

Comment: I meant npm install in cloned generator folder not in jhipster project folder. Anyway could you also try to remove node_modules in project folder and then re-run npm install there because you have a jhipster local copy there or you could try to generate a new project